# Error:Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting below error in android studio.

Gradle sync failed: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

[image]

my gradle file is as below. i cannot find the solution. now the same error is getting in all my projects.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @MichaelDodd i have added build.gradle

Comment: The error message looks like there's a file not encoded in utf8 and that contains a character in e.g. the extended ASCII range.

Comment: but the same error i am getting in my all other projects also. @HeikkiMäenpää

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue...

finally change my classpath in the project build.gradle ... for my case in example it was

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3
```

I first pass it to

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+
```

and once the gradle synced turn it back to

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3
```